# How to package psutil with py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

The app is working fine on my development win8 environment, but when it is packaged with py2exe and run on the production machine it throw the exception:

"The procedure entry point RtlIdnToAscii could not be located in the dynamic link library ntdll.dll"

The detail content of the log file is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DataviewerBackupRestorer.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "RestorController.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "psutil\__init__.pyc", line 136, in <module>
  File "psutil\_psmswindows.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "_psutil_mswindows.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "_psutil_mswindows.pyc", line 10, in __load
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

It seems that a dll required by [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) is missing during the package process. I have tried to add the py2exe options with

```
py2exe_options = {"py2exe":{"includes":['decimal', '_mssql', 'uuid', 'psutil', '_psutil_mswindows']}}
```

But it is not working. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am trying to solve the exact same problem myself so I can't give you an answer but I believe that the message that py2exe gives, "The following modules appear to be missing," may have something to do with the problem. Many of the listed things below pertain to psutil. The missing modules are _psutil_bsd, _psutil_linux, _psutil_osx, _psutil_posix, and _psutil_sunos. Strangely eneough, the missing _psutil_mswindows is not there.

Comment: By the way a dll file should be packaged using the "resource_files" option in setup, the "includes" option is only for python modules that for some reason failed to be included.

Comment: @someone-or-other, Thanks for your suggestions, I have fixed this issue by add several dlls into exclude list. These are py2exe_options = {"py2exe":{"includes": ['decimal', '_mssql', 'uuid'],
                "dll_excludes":["mswsock.dll",
                "powrprof.dll",
                "user32.dll",
                "shell32.dll",
                "wsock32.dll",
                "advapi32.dll",
                "kernel32.dll",
                "ntwdblib.dll",
                "ws2_32.dll",
                "oleaut32.dll",
                "ole32.dll"],
}}

Comment: @someone-or-other, I have rechecked my code, I just bypass the issue but not fix it. I use wmi(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) and the os's default command line to do the jobs. Thanks for your sharing again.

Comment: I am actually also now using wmi :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to remove System DLLs from the project directory. When I added psutil to my application py2exe added a lot of system DLLs to my project. It worked correctly on my and some other computers, but failed on another one. Removing from the project the .dll files that were available in C:\Windows\System32 solved the issue.

Finally in my case the solution was to add:

```
            'dll_excludes': [ "IPHLPAPI.DLL", "NSI.dll",  "WINNSI.DLL",  "WTSAPI32.dll"]
```

into the py2exe options in setup.py file.